# script for getting extensions of a file

Tags: file, bash

I need to get all the file extension types in a folder. For instance, if the directory's ls gives the following:

```
a.t  
b.t.pg  
c.bin  
d.bin  
e.old  
f.txt  
g.txt
```

I should get this by running the script

```
.t  
.t.pg  
.bin  
.old  
.txt
```

I have a bash shell.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/^[^.]*\(\..*\)$/\1/' | sort -u
```

- `ls` lists files in your folder, one file per line
- `sed` magic extracts extensions
- `sort -u` sorts extensions and removes duplicates

sed magic reads as:

- `s/ / /`: substitutes whatever is between first and second / by whatever is between second and third /
- `^`: match beginning of line
- `[^.]`: match any character that is not a dot
- `*`: match it as many times as possible
- `\(` and `\)`: remember whatever is matched between these two parentheses
- `\.`: match a dot
- `.`: match any character
- `*`: match it as many times as possible
- `$`: match end of line
- `\1`: this is what has been matched between parentheses

Answer (score 7):

See [the BashFAQ entry on ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a description of why many of these answers are evil.

The following approach avoids this pitfall (and, by the way, completely ignores files with no extension):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.*; do
  printf '%s\n' ".${f#*.}"
done | sort -u
```

Among the advantages:

- Correctness: `ls` behaves inconsistently and can result in inappropriate results. See the link at the top.
- Efficiency: Minimizes the number of subprocess invoked (only one, `sort -u`, and that could be removed also if we wanted to use Bash 4's associative arrays to store results)

Things that still could be improved:

- Correctness: this will correctly discard newlines in filenames before the first `.` (which some other answers won't) -- but filenames with newlines after the first `.` will be treated as separate entries by `sort`. This could be fixed by using nulls as the delimiter, or by the aforementioned bash 4 associative-array storage approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if a file is a.bin@, this script is removing the @ at the end. But I want the @ too.

Comment: @user640639 err, the `@` isn't part of the file name, it's a sigil added by `ls` listing its type -- you couldn't do `ls foo.bin@`, you'd have to do `ls foo.bin`. So, what you're asking for isn't really the extension then.

Comment: If the user wants to see an `@` at the end this could be added manually in the `printf` statement.

Answer (score 0):

People are really over-complicating this - particularly the regex:

```
ls | grep -o "\..*" | uniq
```

`ls` - get all the files
`grep -o "\..*"` - `-o` only show the match; `"\..*"` match at the first "." & everything after it
`uniq` - don't print duplicates but keep the same order

you can also sort if you like, but sorting doesn't match the example

This is what happens when you run it:

```
> ls -1
a.t
a.t.pg
c.bin
d.bin
e.old
f.txt
g.txt

> ls | grep -o "\..*" | uniq
.t
.t.pg
.bin
.old
.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. But this returned without any output. Dont know why. And sorry about the misunderstanding/incomplete question, but sort is a useful feature I didnt know/include in the question.